# VScode "linkedEditing" not working for php files

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to be able to easily edit HTML tags together. There is a built-in option for this in Visual Studio Code.

[image]

It works fine for HTML files. Buy why not for php files?
Does anybody know a work-around?

For example, let's say I wanted to change this div into a section. It should automatically select both opening tag and the closing tag.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have html inside a PHP file.  The simplest solution would be:

1. double click the element to edit
2. Holding control key double click the closing element ( open and close elements should be highlighted now)
3. type to edit the element

Comment: I added an example.

Answer (score 1):

For now VS Code doesn't handle PHP with `editor.linkedEditing`.

But you can install [Auto Tag Rename](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.auto-rename-tag) extension which will work for PHP files as well.

The extension will ignore certain file types if `editor.linkedEditing = true`, so you can install it without any conflicts.